# SVG animateMotion along circle instead on path

Tags: xml, animation, svg, adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to make an object move, not along the path, but along a circle?
For example:

```
<animateMotion path="M 0,0 C -50,100 -150,100 -200,0" begin="2s" dur="3s" fill="freeze" />
```

This works because we added a path.

Is there a way to do it where you can replace a path with a circle (in this example), or with any other object?

```
<animateMotion
<circle cx="865.9" cy="539.6" r="499.1"/>
begin="2s" dur="3s" fill="freeze" />
```

Also, only using SVG, no HTML (need to send a project as .SVG file)

Comment: Sure just use Firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a circle as a path. For example this circle

```
 <circle cx="865.9" cy="539.6" r="499.1" />
```

can be written like a path using the arc (A) command like so:

```
  <path d="M1365,539.6
           A499.1,499.1 0 1 1 366.8,539.6 
           A499.1,499.1 0 1 1 1365,539.6" />
```

you can use the d atribute of this path for the animation:

```css
svg{width:100vh; border:solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="250 0 1300 1100">
  <path d="M25,-25v50h-50v-50z">
    <animateMotion path="M1365,539.6A499.1,499.1 0 1 1 366.8,539.6 A499.1,499.1 0 1 1 1365,539.6" begin="2s" dur="3s" fill="freeze" /> 
  </path>
 
 
  <circle cx="865.9" cy="539.6" r="499.1" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
  

</svg>
```

Comment: This works great, but I ended up using a path drawer that can convert it to code, and it's gonna be faster for me cause I have many moving objects (making a Solar System)

Comment: Orbits are not circular, they are elliptical but it still looks fine, so i won't bother changing...